# Creating stopwatch using Javascript: Having trouble with click event

Tags: javascript, date, addeventlistener

I'm currently working on [this Mozilla Developer Network's project](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals#Active_learning_Creating_your_own_stopwatch!). The assignment is to create a stop watch using the date object and some plain old Javascript, and things are coming together slowly.

I've figured out the logic behind showing the elapse of time using the Date.now() method, and have been able to show a successful elapse of time. Only issue is, this only happens when the html element is clicked. I want the elapse of time to continue showing on the screen without having to keep clicking.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Here's the link to the assignment: https://github.uconn.edu/pages/ssw19002/dmd-3475/Week-9/stop-watch/stop-watch.html

Here's the code so far:

```
function displayTime() {
  let date = new Date();
  let time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.querySelector('.clock').textContent = time;
}


const createClock = setInterval(displayTime,1000);


//add click event to start button
let startBtn = document.getElementById("start-button");

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.clock').textContent = setInterval(function startTime(){startTime - Date.now()}, 1000);

  const createClock = setInterval(startTime,1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one I made for command line use. Perhaps you can modify it for browser
use:

```
function format(d) {
   let mil = String(d % 1000).padStart(3, '0');
   d = Math.trunc(d / 1000);
   let sec = String(d % 60).padStart(2, '0');
   d = Math.trunc(d / 60);
   return String(d) + ' m ' + sec + ' s ' + mil + ' ms';
}

function main() {
   console.clear();
   let s = format(Date.now() - n);
   console.log(s);
}

let n = Date.now();
setInterval(main, 10);
```

https://89z.github.io/autumn/return-duration-string/js

Comment: My issue is not with the math/logic I just don't understand why I have to keep clicking to get the timer to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Just the first two definitions should be enough for the clock part. `setInterval` will start an interval that calls `displayTime` every second. Make a second function `displayElapsedTime` that is similar to `displayTime`, and inside the `startBtn` click handler, *stop* the `displayTime` interval (you'll need to hold onto the result of the `setInterval` call to be able to do this) and *start* the `displayElapsedTime` interval. [As always, read the best / most official documentation you can find on how to do this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

The code you posted has a bug - the body of the function you named `startTime` contains a reference to a variable named `startTime` - which will then point to the function `startTime`. It seems you named the *function* itself startTime instead of naming a variable defined inside the function.